# Chat link from Area 51 should link to chat for Area 51 Discussion Zone

Tags: bug, chat, area-51

Searching for [Area 51-related chatrooms](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=area51.stackexchange.com) through the "chat" link in the Stack Exchange drop-down menu shows a list of chat rooms parented to `area51.stackexchange.com`, which doesn't have any chat rooms:

[image: Area 51 chat screenshot]

However, if I click on *(more sites…)* and then select *Area 51* from the dropdown, I get directed to a list of chat rooms parented to *discuss.area51.stackexchange.com*, which is not empty:

[image]

Although the pages look identical, the second page actually shows [rooms about Area 51 *Discussion Zone*](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active&host=discuss.area51.stackexchange.com).

This is rather confusing. It would be better if the link in the dropdown menu linked to chat rooms for the Area 51 Discussion Zone, like the direct link in the top-bar (to the right of the username) already does.

Comment: Why not? Because no one created any.

Comment: @Oded I just noticed three are shown when I take a different route, so it's apparentnly rather an interface bug/wart

Comment: Oh, I see the difference; one is for `area51.stackexchange.com`, the other for `discuss.area51.stackexchange.com`…

Comment: This is because Area 51 is old and using different code base, so it has no chat. Its "meta" site, aka Discussion Zone, is using the current code base, thus can have chat rooms associated with it.

Comment: @ShadowWizard But it still has a Chat-link in its top-bar…

Comment: Looks like the chat link to the right of the user name does work, only the chat link under the Stack Exchange dropdown is "broken" since it's adding the wrong `host=area51.stackexchange.com` parameter. (should be `host=discuss.area51.stackexchange.com`.)

Comment: @ShadowWizard That is right.  I had not even noticed the first one (probably because other sites don't have this link).

Comment: Semi-related: [Move all chat rooms hosted with discuss.Area51 to Area51.meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/300476/335251) – Choosing "Area 51" in the dropdown for the parent site to create a chat room on now parents the room to `area51.meta.stackexchange.com`, but there are older chat rooms still parented to `discuss.area51.stackexchange.com`, so there are separate lists of rooms parented to each site.

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: [No chat rooms showing for Area51 (Change URL to add "discuss")](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/293522/335251) – both your post and the linked one seem to be reporting the same issue, with the same solution. One of the two should probably be closed as a duplicate of the other.

Comment: Interestingly, the "chat" link on [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com)'s top bar (ignore the design bug with the top bar's look for now) seems to work fine – the URL just says `https://chat.stackexchange.com/`, but seems to show the same [list of chat rooms parented to `discuss.area51.stackexchange.com`](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active&host=discuss.area51.stackexchange.com). The problem only occurs with the link that appears in the dropdown on [Area 51 Discussions](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com) itself.