# No chat rooms showing for Area 51 (change URL to add "meta")

Tags: bug, chat, area-51, hyperlinks, stack-exchange-button

The [chat link](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=area51.stackexchange.com) from the Stack Exchange (menu) bar or from the bottom panel is not showing any chat rooms for Area 51:

[image]

[image]

Even the "show frozen/deleted rooms" button doesn't show any rooms.

I found that chat rooms are visible if I change the URL from

- https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=area51.stackexchange.com (wrong) to
- [https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site& host=area51.**meta**.stackexchange.com](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=area51.meta.stackexchange.com) (right) which used if we select Area 51 from the drop-down list through https://chat.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: I think a51 should draw more attention from the SE (company), particularly if we compare the [growth stats of the site networks](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/652078/comparing-the-growth-of-the-so-to-the-se-by-month#graph).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1092/discussion-between-nobodynada-and-peterh).

Comment: It's even stranger when you consider that Area 51 Discussions now uses area51.meta, but the proper chat link still uses discuss.area51.

Comment: Weirdly, both [`discuss.area51.`](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=discuss.area51.stackexchange.com) and [`area51.meta.`](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=area51.meta.stackexchange.com) have chat rooms parented to them, but different rooms are parented to each. Related: [Move all chat rooms hosted with discuss.Area51 to Area51.meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/300476/335251) (EDIT: This is now fixed for the remaining active rooms, so I've re-edited your post to point to the latter rather than the former.)

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: [Chat-link from Area51 should link to chat for Area51 Discussion Zone](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/286981/335251) – both your post and the linked one seem to be reporting the same issue, with the same solution. One of the two should probably be closed as a duplicate of the other.

Comment: Interestingly, the "chat" link on [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com)'s own top bar (ignore the design bug with the top bar's look for now) seems to work fine – the URL just says `https://chat.stackexchange.com/`, but seems to show the same [list of chat rooms parented to `discuss.area51.stackexchange.com`](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active&host=discuss.area51.stackexchange.com). The problem only occurs with the link that appears in the dropdown on [Area 51 Discussions](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com) itself.